# Use of apostrophe or hyphen in money amounts

Tags: hyphenation, apostrophe, money, worth

I'm trying to write a sentence along the lines of "we ordered 200 pounds' worth of stuff", but using the pound sign rather than the word.
Possible options:
"£200 worth"
"£200's worth"
"£200-worth"
"£200's-worth"

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Even though £200 is read as 200 pounds, I'd put in the apostrophe-s as easier to process for the reader. In spite of the modern trend to drop apostrophes for non-possessive usages. Also the hyphen, to avoid a possible garden-path scenario. This is a matter of style rather than absolute right and wrong, so I'd aim for the clearest option.

Comment: I think any of those would be acceptable, though personally I don't much like the one with the hyphen.